# How to change properties of two elements at the same time using hover in CSS

Tags: css, hover

I need to achieve this: 
when I hover at the red box, the purple one should disappear, when I hover over the orange one, blue one should disappear and then I hove over the yellow one, the green one disappears. I managed to do that, however I need to do it in reverse, too, but everything I tried didn't work. Could anyone help me?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Boxes</title>
    <style type"text/css">
    div {
        width:70px;
        height:90px;
        border:3px solid #000;
    }
    .t1 {
        background: red;
        top: 50px;
        left: 15px; 
        position: absolute;
    }
    .t1:hover + .t6{
        background: red;
        top: 50px;
        left: 15px; 
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: invisible;
    }
    .t2 {
        position: absolute;
        background:orange;
        top: 100px;
        left: 60px;
    }
    .t2:hover + .t5 {
        position: absolute;
        background:orange;
        top: 100px;
        left: 60px;
        z-index: 1;
        visibility: invisible;
    }
    .t3 {
        background:yellow;
        top: 150px;
        left: 110px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .t3:hover + .t4 {
        background:yellow;
        top: 150px;
        left: 110px;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: invisible;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .t4 {
        background:green;
        top: 200px;
        left: 160px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .t5 {
        background:blue;
        top: 250px;
        left: 210px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .t6 {
        background:purple;
        top: 300px;
        left: 260px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
    }


    <!--backwards-->


    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="t1"></div>
    <div class="t6"></div>
    <div class="t2"></div>
    <div class="t5"></div>
    <div class="t3"></div>
    <div class="t4"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: `invisible` is not a valid option for [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility), you want `hidden` instead

Comment: Only if you can wait for the [level 4 selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible**! with some tricks :P just reorder some boxes and play with containers.

**Final solution**: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7km/4/

I am just playing with CSS but you can check my work: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7km/

```
<div class="cont" id="cont1" >
  <div id="d1" ></div>
  <div id="d2" ></div>
</div>
```

Here is the magic code:

```
.cont div:first-child:hover + div {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.cont:hover div:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.cont:hover div:first-child:hover {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Updated!: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7km/2/

Two more and code refactoring.

Almost done: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7km/3/

It is done: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7km/4/

Thanks to let me play :-)

Comment: Thank YOU! :)  
I was trying to do it with nesting but would always mess the order...

Answer (score 1):

CSS only currently works in a "downward" way. This means that you can only go from parent to child or first sibling to next sibling. You can't go "up" - child to parent or second sibling to first.

In other words, you can do `t1 + t6` (select t6 when it's next to t1), but you can't do `t6 + t1` (select t1 when it's next to t6) with your current HTML structure, because t1 comes before t6.

The only way to traverse up the DOM is to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible with CSS alone. Use JavaScript instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed. I have to do it using only css and html

Comment: Well CSS doesn't have the functionality required to select other elements in the parent, only the current element's siblings.

Comment: <div id="first">
    <div class="t1"></div>
    <div class="t6"></div>
</div>

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. JavaScript is the only way.